# Is there a possible way to respond a call via code in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a program which can access the Microsoft Teams online with Selenium and Python.
Every time I get a call, I want my program to accept the incoming call automatically.

All these Steps are required to login Teams.
Thank you for helping.
Kind regards.

```
username = 'xx'
passwort = 'xx'

url1 = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1584303675&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Fauth%2Fcomplete-signin%3Fru%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.microsoft.com%252F%253Flang%253Dde-ch%2526refd%253Daccount.microsoft.com%2526refp%253Dsignedout-index&lc=1031&id=292666&lw=1&fl=easi2&ru=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Faccount%3Flang%3Dde-ch'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"\Users\xxx\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url1)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_name('loginfmt').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('passwordInput').send_keys(passwort)
driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()
```

Comment: Yes, it certainly seems like it should be possible. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource, please see [ask] and [help/on-topic].